# How can i have an image on a scene 10 times in a row without having to create a sprite for it everytime?

Tags: c++, cocos2d-x

I'm trying to develop a game in cocos2d-x and want one image on the scene to be repeated 10 times in one row. Can a do it in a function and call it again using setPosition wherever I want that image?

Suppose the function name is `point()` where I have defeinition:

```
auto sprite = Sprite::create("point.png");
```

and function returns the sprite.

So can I create a sprite in it using that function and call it like

```
point()->setPosition(40, 40);
```

Comment: Can you put your code in a proper format please ?

Answer (score 0):

```
Sprite* GenerateScene::point()
{
  auto sprite6 = Sprite::create("point.png");
  sprite6->setAnchorPoint(Vec2(0.0, 0.0));

  return sprite6;
}

bool GenerateScene::init()
{
  auto sprite = Sprite::create("bkgnd.png");
  sprite->setAnchorPoint(Vec2(0.0, 0.0));

  sprite->addChild(point());

  sprite->setPosition(0, 0);

  point()->setPosition(120, 480);
}
```

This piece of code here only generates an "point.png" at (0, 0) location of the background image i.e. bottom left corner. It is not considering

```
point()->setPosition(120, 480);
```

statement.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The purpose of a Sprite is to repeat an image on the screen.

If you looked at the Sprite::create source you would see that creating 10 sprites with the same image does not create and load 10 images. Instead there is a `SpriteFrameCache` that caches the actual image. Each of the 10 Sprites would be just a lighweight reference to an instance of that one image in the Scene.